# php string as function parameter contains required comma and messes up functionality

Tags: php, string

I have a mail() function and I'm passing in a name alongside the email address and some of these names contain commas (because some names in the database contain titles).

**Example:** *Random Person, MD*

The issue is that when I'm passing a string with a comma into my mail function, it looks like this to PHP:

**Function:**

```
mail($name.' <'.$email.'>',$subject,$message,$headers);
```

"To" parameter with example translated string:

```
mail('Random Person, MD <person@place.com>', ...
```

So when the email goes out, it sends to multiple email addresses because it uses the comma as a separator, somewhat like this:

- (Random@web.myserver.com)
- (Person@web.myserver.com)
- MD (person@place.com)

I noticed it also seems to translate spaces like that also, but if I can find a solution to enclose the string properly, I'm sure that will fix itself.

I could use str_replace() to take out the commas or maybe change them to an alternative character or take out the name altogether, but anyone have any ideas on how I might pass the commas into the string without the function translating it literally?

Comment: And if you try doing `mail('"'.$name'"  <'.$email.'>',$subject,$message,$headers);`

Comment: I did a test send and I received an email without the name in the "to" line.  It might be sending out separate email(s) that will bounce with the name(s) in them; I can't immediately tell because the email I received has only the email address in it without the name.

Comment: use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and save time and trouble with escaping / encoding / attachments etc..

Comment: That's one way, but there's got to be some simple solution to make this work properly.